# Возвращение только значащих величин из строки с пробелами в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли в python функция которая превращала бы строку "  p" в "p"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ваших целей может подойти одно из следующих решений:

```
s1 = " p".strip() # удаляет пробелы, табы, переносы в начале и в конце строки. Если нужно удалять другие символы - их нужно передать как аргумент
s2 = " p".split() # разбивает строку по пробелам. 

print(s1, s2, sep="\n")
```

Результат:

```
p
['p']
```